# Populate contact field based on email

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

We're doing a demo of Survey Monkey and can't seem to get the contact populated from the form mapping.  My solve for this would be to make a trigger that looks at the required email field and finds a matching contact to relate to that record. Doesn't solve for duplicates, but that's just something we've learned to deal with.  I know this isn't difficult, but with my lack of knowledge on code and my inability to find something on the interwebs, I thought I would ask the pros.

```
trigger ContactUpdate on Coaching_Survey__c (before insert, before update) {

Contact c;

for(Coaching_Survey__c survey : Trigger.new){

    survey.Contact__c = [SELECT [SELECT id FROM Contact WHERE email=:survey.Email__c LIMIT 1];

    update survey;
}
```

}

Getting an error of:

> Invalid assignment List to Id.

Then tried to go the route of:

```
trigger ContactUpdate on Coaching_Survey__c (before insert, before update) {

for(Coaching_Survey__c survey : Trigger.new){

    List<Contact> c = [SELECT id FROM Contact WHERE email=:survey.Email__c LIMIT 1];
    survey.Contact__c = c.get(0).Id;

    update survey;
}
```

}

And received an error upon saving the record of:

> Error:Apex trigger ContactUpdate caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: ContactUpdate: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0: Trigger.ContactUpdate: line 6, column 1

I wish I could tell you I have any idea what I'm doing, but I'm self taught with all of this and unfortunately don't have the time I'd like to be able to sit down a couple hours a day to broaden my knowledge.  I appreciate ya'lls help!

Answer (score 0):

Killed two birds with one stone.  Ended up being able to get this to work while also adding a layer of validation to pick the correct contact if the emails matched:

```
trigger ContactUpdate on Coaching_Survey__c (before insert, before update) {

for(Coaching_Survey__c survey : Trigger.new){

    List<Contact> c = [SELECT id FROM Contact WHERE Membership__c like 'Active' AND email=:survey.Email__c LIMIT 1];
    if(c.size() > 0 && survey.Contact__c == null) {
        survey.Contact__c = c.get(0).Id;
    }
}
```

}